# Each Iteration of for loop value should be sum up outside the forloop

Tags: robotframework

I am just trying the below scenario in robot framework
For Loop will run 2 times. Each time it will store a value in variable x
Assume first run, it stored x=5 and in the second run x=2.
Now i want sum of x in outside loop

```
For {i} IN RANGE 0    2
${x}=    Get Element Count    //tbody/tr
LOG  ${x}
Click Element    //tbody/tr`
END
```

Both the iteration was successful, now i want to sum of X in outside loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an int type for the storage, but a list; the result of every iteration will be appended to it, and at the end you can sum the list members.
Sample:

```
${results}=    Create List
FOR    {i}    IN RANGE    0    2
    ${x}=    Get Element Count    //tbody/tr
    Log  ${x}
    Append To List    ${results}    ${x}
    Click Element    //tbody/tr
END
# now you just need to sum all members; 
# this is just one way to do it, with python's sum() function and accessing the variable itself ($results vs ${results}) 
${sum}=     Evaluate    sum(x for x in $results)
Log    The sum is ${sum}
```